# Can I use factory functions to bind Rows and Columns in "sap.ui.table.Table" control?

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

I am using XML views to create views in my SAPUI5 project. I was trying to implement factory functions to use for Columns & Rows of a sap.ui.Table control. Column factory seems to be working fine but for some reason Row factory never gets executed.

View:

```xml
<table:Table xmlns:table="sap.ui.table"
  columns="{
    path: 'oModel>/columns',
    factory: '.colFactory'
  }"
  rows="{
    path: 'oModel>/rows',
    factory: '.rowFactory'
  }"
>
  <!-- ... -->
</table:Table>
```

Controller:

```js
// Column required from "sap/ui/table/Column"
// Row required from "sap/ui/table/Row"

colFactory: function(sId, oContext) {
  // ...
  return new Column({/*...*/});
},
rowFactory: function(sId, oContext) {
  // ...
  return new Row({/*...*/});
},
```

I have implemented a dynamic binding of both `Rows` and `Columns` as per a specific requirement. Can someone please suggest or help me here? Can get my head around thinking what is missing or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The use of **`factory` function is [intentionally left out](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/866#issuecomment-187830418) for `sap.ui.table.Table`** in order to deal with huge amounts of data in contrast to `sap.m.Table`. The grid table (`sap.ui.table.Table`) reuses its existing DOM element when the user scrolls, which is incompatible with how factory functions work.

If you really need to use a `factory` function, I'm afraid there is no other way than implementing `sap.m.Table` instead (although the performance will suffer). If not, define [templates](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.table.Column#constructor) in the Column controls.

Please review also the documentation topic *[Tables: Which One Should I Choose?](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/148892ff9aea4a18b912829791e38f3e)*